# Abel-Plana formula for $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

First, we derive the alternating sum version of Abel-Plana formula, i.e

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^kf(k)$$

Start with the [Abel-Plana formula, Eq. 2.10.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10)

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=a}^n f(k)&=\int_a^n f(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f(n)-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(a+iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy\\
&+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=n}+\hat{R}\end{align}\tag{0}$$

where $\hat{R}=\hat{R}(m,n)$ is the remainder term and it depends on $m , n$. Here $B_{2s}$ are Bernoulli numbers.

Set $a=0, n=2N$

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{2N} f(k)&=\int_0^{2N} f(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f(2N)-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy\\
&+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_1}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Next, set $a=0, n=N$

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{N} g(k)&=\int_0^{N} g(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}g(0)+\frac{1}{2}g(N)-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(g(iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy\\
&+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}g^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=N}+\hat{R_2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

Let $g(x)=f(2x)$, eq.(2) becomes

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{N} f(2k)&=\color{red}{\int_0^{N} f(2x)dx}+\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f(2N)\color{blue}{-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(2iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy}\\
&+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}2^{2s-1}f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_2}\tag{3}\end{align}$$

Let $t=2x, \theta=2y$

$$\color{red}{\int_0^{N} f(2x)dx}=\frac{1}2\int_0^{2N} f(t)dt,~~~~~~\color{blue}{-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(2iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy}=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(i\theta)\right)}{e^{\pi \theta}-1}d\theta$$

So eq.(3) becomes:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{N} f(2k)&=\frac{1}2\int_0^{2N} f(t)dt+\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f(2N)-\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(i\theta)\right)}{e^{\pi \theta}-1}d\theta\\
&+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}2^{2s-1}f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_2}\tag{3'}\end{align}$$

Now, we use $2\times (3')-(1)$ to get the alternating sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^kf(k)=2\sum_{k=0}^{N} f(2k)-\sum_{k=0}^{2N} f(k)$$

also note that

$$-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(i\theta)\right)}{e^{\pi \theta}-1}d\theta+2\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(iy)\right)}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(it)\right)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt$$

So we get the formula for alternating sum

$$\begin{align}\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^kf(k)=\frac{f(0)+f(2N)}{2}-\int_0^\infty \frac{\Im\left(f(it)\right)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}(4^s-1)f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_3}}\tag{4}\end{align}$$

where $\hat{R_3}=2\hat{R_2}-\hat{R_1}$ is the remainder term.

**Verify formulas:**

Set $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, we get [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491717/use-abel-plana-formula-to-calculate-an-integral-int-0-infty-frac-arctant) by using eq.(0)

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{e^{2\pi x}-1} dx =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\ln(2\pi)$$

Set $f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{(2x+2)^2}{(2x+1)(2x+3)} \right), $ we get this integral by using eq.(0), which is related to [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{2\arctan (x)-\arctan (2x)-\arctan\left(\frac{2}3x\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=\frac{1}2\ln\left(\frac{3}\pi \right)$$

Set $f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x+1} \right), $ we get this integral by using eq.(4), which is related to [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}2\right)-\arctan (x)}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx=\ln\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}\pi \right)$$

Set $f(x)=x, $ we get [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697178/evaluate-integral-int-infty-infty-gamma1ix-gamma1-ixdx/4697431#4697431) by using eq.(4)

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx=\frac{1}4$$

Set $f(x)=x^2, $ we get this trivial result by using eq.(4)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^kk^2=2N^2+N$$

Set $f(x)=x^3, $ we get this integral by using eq.(4)

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx=\frac{1}8$$

**My question**:

Abel-Plana formula requires the function $f(z)$ is bounded by

$$|f(z)| < \frac{C}{|z|^{1+\epsilon}}\text{, with } C>0, \epsilon >0$$

so that the integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ is finite and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\to 0$.

Note that **none** of above cases satisfy this bounded condition, but we all get correct results. So we don't need this bounded condition when we use this partial summation form, i.e. eq.(0) and eq.(4). Is this true?

Comment: Is $f^{(2s-1)}_{(x)} =f^{(2s-1)}(x)$?

Comment: Ah, yes, I have fixed them.

Comment: If you use $\frac{{B_{2s} }}{{(2s)!}}(4^s  - 1) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{E_{2s - 1} (0)}}{{(2s - 1)!}}$ the relation to the [Euler–Boole summation formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.17.i) becomes more apparent. You may try to derive this formula directly without the Abel–Plana formula and see what conditions are required.

Comment: According to the wiki article(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) on Abel-Plana formula, it says that the result follows for bounds much weaker than $O(|z|^{-(1+ε)})$.

Comment: @Fotis Indeed, as it is given in the source the OP is citing: http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.i

Comment: I will look at this, thank you a lot! @Gary